# NDsolve with ODE-PDE

Tags: differential-equations

Kindly I hope to know what is the wrong here. How to use NDsolve for a coupled ODE-PDE differential equations

```
NDSolve[{F''[t]+F[t]==0,
F[0]==0,F'[3*Pi]==1,D[u[t,x],t]==D[u[t,x],x,x],u[0,x]==0,u[t,0]==5*F[t],u[t,5]==0},
{F,u},{t,0,3*Pi},{x,0,5}];
```

I have received the following messages

> Function::fpct: Too many parameters in {t,x} to be filled from
>   Function[{t,x},0][t].
>
> NDSolve::ndode: The equations {(F^[Prime])[3
>   [Pi]]==1,F[t]+(F^[Prime][Prime])[t]==0} are not differential
>   equations or initial conditions in the dependent variables {u}.

Comment: Functions must be defined in the whole area `{t,0,3*Pi},{x,0,5}`. It is necessary to separate the ODE from the PDE. Or calculate the function `F[t,x]`, but then the problem loses its meaning

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. But I want to solve them simultaneously. How I can do that

Answer (score 6):

You can solve for `F` and use that solution to solve for `u`:

```
solF = NDSolve[{F''[t] + F[t] == 0, F[0] == 0, F'[3*Pi] == 1}, {F}, {t, 0, 3*Pi}][[1]];
ff = F /. solF;
Plot[ff[t], {t, 0, 3*Pi}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "F[t]"}]
```

[image]

```
solu = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, 
     u[t, 0] == 5*ff[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, {u}, {t, 0, 3*Pi}, {x, 0, 5}][[1, 1]];
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. solu], {t, 0, 3*Pi}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "u[t,x]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. But I want to solve them simultaneously. How I can do that?

Answer (score 4):

To solve the equations jointly, we need to define the problem so that there is a Cauchy problem. I will propose the option that the solution of the system of equations coincides with that obtained by another method by @kglr

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[F[t, x], t, t] + F[t, x] == D[F[t, x], x, x], 
    F[0, x] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][F][0, x] == -1, 
    Derivative[0, 1][F][t, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][F][t, 5] == 0, 
    D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, 
    u[t, 0] == 5*F[t, 0], u[t, 5] == 0}, {F, u}, {t, 0, 3*Pi}, {x, 0, 
    5}];

{Plot3D[F[t, x] /. sol, {t, 0, 3*Pi}, {x, 0, 5}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "F"], 
 Plot3D[u[t, x] /. sol, {t, 0, 3*Pi}, {x, 0, 5}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "u"]}
```

[image: fig1]