# Coupled ODEs/PDEs with functional initial(boundary?) conditions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to numerically solve the following coupled DEs:

$\frac{d f(t) }{d t} =-f(t); f(0)=1; \frac{\partial g(t,\tau)}{\partial \tau}=-g(t,\tau); g(t,0)=f^2(t)$

It is easy to solve by hand

$f(t)=e^{-t}; g(t,\tau)=e^{-2t -\tau}$

However I am having trouble solving it in Mathematica. I followed [this solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189522/ndsolve-with-ode-pde) and used the following code:

```
fSol = NDSolve[{D[f[t], t] == -f[t], f[0] == 1}, f[t], {t, 0, 5}];
ff[t_] := f[t] /. fSol
gSol = NDSolve[{D[g[t, \[Tau]], \[Tau]] == -g[t, \[Tau]],g[t, 0] == ff[t]*ff[t]}, g[t, \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, 5}]
```

But the second NDSolve gave me the following error

```
NDSolve::ndinnt: Initial condition {<<1>>^2} is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers.
```

What can I do to resolve this?(In the end I would like to generalize this to two systems of DEs instead of just two DEs as shown here but I imagine the solution would be similar)

Comment: initial conditions to NDSolve has to be numeric. Change to `g[t, 0] ==t` and you'll get same error.

Comment: In the solution I linked, it seems the initial condition doesn't have to be numeric? There the poster gave u[t, 0] == 5*ff[t] as part of the conditions for u[t,x], where ff[t] is a function solved numerically previously. It worked there, why not here?

Comment: Sorry, I did not even look at the linked question. I only tried what you have. Will have a look at the linked question now and see why it worked there if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your solution to work, and avoid the error `Initial condition {<<1>>^2} is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers` you need to also give the range of `t`, like this

```
fSol = NDSolve[{D[f[t], t] == -f[t], f[0] == 1}, {f}, {t, 0, 5}][[1]];
ff = f /. fSol;

gSol = NDSolve[{D[g[t, τ], τ] == -g[t, τ], g[t, 0] == ff[t]*ff[t]}, g, 
         {τ, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Becuase now after adding `{t, 0, 5}` to the second `NDSolve`, it is happy, since it can evaluate `ff[t]*ff[t]` as numbers. Without this, you get the error you had.

And it is better to use `f` instead of `f[t]` when using `NDSolve`